# mixing time of random walks on dense Erdos Renyi graphs

Tags: random-walks, random-graphs, erdos, mixing

Is there anything known about the mixing time of a simple random walk on an Erdos-Renyi graph with parameter $\langle n,d \rangle$ where $d=n^a (0<a<1 )$. I know about Reed et al and Benjamini et al's result when $d=\log^a (n)$. But I need to have a denser random graph.

Comment: Here d is the average degree? If so, it is probably ~log(n). If you wish, I can later search for a source.

Comment: Yes, I mean the average degree. Yeah that would be awesome, do you know of any source?

Comment: I believe I found it. It is a paper by Hildebrand. Thanks.